# Deselecting a clicked object

Tags: jquery

```
var infoOnClick = {
        selected: 0, 
    };

    $( ".pion" ).click(function() {

        if(infoOnClick.selected == 0) {

            infoOnClick.selected = 1;

            var selected = this;

            $(selected).toggleClass("box-shadow");

            $( ".coord" ).click(function() {

                $(selected).appendTo(this);

                $(".coord").unbind("click");
                infoOnClick.selected = 0;

            });       

         }
         else {

             $(selected).removeClass("box-shadow");
             var selected = NULL;

         }
    });
```

I have a 10 by 10 field where I want to place pions in. First I want to click the pion and then the right coordinate. For example I want to place pion P4 on position C23. However I can place the pions in the field but I cant move them anymore after they are placed.

When I remove `$(".coord").unbind("click");` I can replace the pions in the field but it will select all the pions I clicked. So there will be 2 pions on one position (and 3 if I try it again etc).

Does someone know how to fix this?

```
    <table>

        <?php

        $player = 'p1';

        if($player == 'p1') {

            $kleur = 'rood'; 
            $player == 1; 
        }

        if($player == 'p2') {

            $kleur = 'blauw'; 
            $player == 2; 

        }

        for ($y = 9; $y >= 0; $y--) {
            echo '<tr>'
            . '';
            for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
                echo '<td class="coord" id="c' . $x . $y . '"></td>'
                . '';
            }
            echo'</tr>'
            . '';
        }

        ?>


    </table>

    <div class='pion-venster'>

        <?php

        for ($y = 39; $y >= 0; $y--) {

        echo '<div class="pion ' . $kleur . ' " id="p' . $y . '"></div>';

        }

        ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: I would move the coord click binding to outside the pion click event otherwise you will bind a new pion click everytime you click a pion.  Also can you show the html so we can see how pion and coord are related

Comment: I think it is nessecary to keep the click event for coord inside the pion click event since we need the information from the pion clicked in order to move the right pion. I also added the html (php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

1. bind the click events seperately
2. make the selected object global
3. only add pion if coord is empty (no need for binding and unbinding then)

```js
var selectedItem = null,
  pions = $(".pion"),
  coords = $(".coord");

$(document).on('click', '.pion', function() {
  pions.removeClass("box-shadow");  // remove class from  any p[reviously selected pion

  if (selectedItem == $(this)) {
    selectedItem = null;            // if selected pion is current clicked one, deselect
  } else {
    selectedItem = $(this);         // otherwise select
    selectedItem.addClass("box-shadow");
  }
});


coords.click(function () {
  var currentCoord = $(this);
  if (selectedItem != null) { // only append selected item if coord is empty
    if (!currentCoord.children().length) {
      currentCoord.append(selectedItem);
    }

    selectedItem.removeClass("box-shadow");  // deselect
    selectedItem = null;
  } 
});
```

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4oh6x7zv/)

Comment: I got the same problem that I cant slect a pion inside the field.

Comment: Ah ok that's weird.  You need to delegate the first click event: See edit above with fiddle

Comment: I only have a hard time understanding this line:

Comment: if (!currentCoord.children().length) {
                currentCoord.append(selectedItem);
            }

Comment: @JohanStaart, that line means that if the coord is empty, then add the pion - it stops you adding multiple pions to the same coord

Comment: I understand now! Much apreaciated! Thanks!